# Android file system scan very slow

Tags: android, file, directory, filesystems

For my app, I want to keep track of changes made to the filesystem, modified/deleted/new files. Scanning seems kind of slow for this usecase. Gallery/Photo apps seem to scan the whole system without any problems, does anybody have an idea how they do that?

Scanning on linux is no problem, but on android it takes 1000 times longer and I don't really understand why.

- linux= Folders: 12895 Files: 106848 Time: 1.511173963546753
- android= Folders: 78 Files: 4092 Time: 3.0804240703582764

Comment: Then which app do you use on Android to scan? How did you measure?

Comment: `Gallery/Photo apps seem to scan the whole system ` There is no gallery on an Android device and Photo apps to not scan themselves.

Comment: Your Time is in hours? Days?